# A concise way to extract some elements of a "survfit" object into a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I load a data set from the `survival` library, and generate a `survfit` object:

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
lung$SurvObj <- with(lung, Surv(time, status == 2))
fit <- survfit(SurvObj ~ 1, data = lung, conf.type = "log-log")
```

This object is a list:

```
> str(fit)
List of 13
 $ n        : int 228
 $ time     : int [1:186] 5 11 12 13 15 26 30 31 53 54 ...
 $ n.risk   : num [1:186] 228 227 224 223 221 220 219 218 217 215 ...
 $ n.event  : num [1:186] 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 ...
```

Now I specify some members (all same length) that I want to turn into a data frame:

```
members <- c("time", "n.risk", "n.event")
```

I'm looking for a concise way to make a data frame with the three list members as columns, with the columns named `time`, `n.risk`, `n.event` (**not** `fit$time`, `fit$n.risk`, `fit$n.event`)

Thus the resulting data frame should look like this:

```
           time     n.risk       n.event
  [1,]        5        228             1
  [2,]       11        227             3
  [3,]       12        224             1
  ...
```

Comment: What is the expected output suppose to look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is OK

```
data.frame(unclass(fit)[members])
```

Another (more canonical) way is

```
with(fit, data.frame(time, n.risk, n.event))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `broom`package contains functions to tidy up the results of  regression models and present them in an object of class `data.frame`. For those unfamiliar with the tidy philosophy, please see [Tidy data [ 1 ]](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10)

```
library(broom)
#create tidy dataframe and subset by the columns saved in members
df <- tidy(fit)[,members]
head(df)
#  time n.risk n.event
#1    5    228       1
#2   11    227       3
#3   12    224       1
#4   13    223       2
#5   15    221       1
#6   26    220       1
```

[ 1 ] Wickham, Hadley . "Tidy Data." Journal of Statistical Software [Online], 59.10 (2014): 1 - 23. Web. 16 Jun. 2017

Answer (score 0):

Used cbind to bind the dataframes, then used names to change the name of columns

```
        time=as.data.frame(fit$time)
        n.risk=as.data.frame(fit$n.risk)
        n.event=as.data.frame(fit$n.event)
        members2=cbind(time,n.risk,n.event)
        names(members2)=c("time","n.risk","n.event")
     head(members2)
      time n.risk n.event
    1    5    228       1
    2   11    227       3
    3   12    224       1
    4   13    223       2
    5   15    221       1
    6   26    220       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
lung$SurvObj <- with(lung, Surv(time, status == 2))
fit <- survfit(SurvObj ~ 1, data = lung, conf.type = "log-log")
str(fit)
members<-data.frame(time=fit$time,n.risk=fit$n.risk,n.event=fit$n.event)
members
```

Comment: **members<-data.frame(time=fit$time,n.risk=fit$n.risk,n.event=fit$n.event)**